# Is there a way to pause and resume activity during a Espresso test?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

What i want to do is very simple, i just want to test my IllegalState (during fragment commit) logic behind my activities.
I want to pause the activity, try to commit a fragment and then asserts that i'm handling this right.

But it seems to be not possible to actually pause and then resume activity during Espresso tests. Is there a way to do this without launching another activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quintin is correct in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65125497/1071320) to point you to the [ActivityScenario.moveToState(newState:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#movetostate) method but he is missing some details which I hope to fill here.

First of all, note that the [ActivityScenario.launch(activityClass:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#launch(java.lang.Class%3CA%3E)) method not only launches the activity but waits for its lifecycle state transitions to be complete. So, unless you're calling [Activity.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) in your activity's lifecycle event methods, you can assume that it is in a [RESUMED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#RESUMED) state by the time the [ActivityScenario.launch(activityClass:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#launch(java.lang.Class%3CA%3E)) method returns.

Secondly, once your activity is launched and in a [RESUMED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#RESUMED) state, then moving it back to the [STARTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#STARTED) state will actually cause your activity's [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause()) method to be called. Likewise, moving the activity back to the [CREATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#created) state, will cause both its [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause()) and [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onStop()) methods to be called.

Thirdly, once you've moved the activity back to the [CREATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#created) or [STARTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#STARTED) state, you have to move it forward to the [RESUMED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#RESUMED) state before you can perform view assertions and view actions on it, or otherwise your test method will throw a [NoActivityResumedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/NoActivityResumedException).

All of the above is summarised in the following test method:

```
@Test
fun moving_activity_back_to_started_state_and_then_forward_to_resumed_state() {
    val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity::class.java)

    // the activity's onCreate, onStart and onResume methods have been called at this point

    activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)

    // the activity's onPause method has been called at this point

    activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

    // the activity's onResume method has been called at this point
}
```

To see this in action, refer to [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-espresso-experiments/tree/master/app1) sample application and [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-espresso-experiments/blob/master/app1/src/androidTest/java/com/tazkiyatech/espresso/experiments/app1/MainActivityTest.kt) test class in particular.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario), but they do not include `Pause` as a State. You might get away with the [`recreate()` method](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing#recreate), but that is Pausing and Resuming.

```
    //possibly:
    // @get:Rule var activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<MyActivity>()

    val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity::class.java)
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    //...
    scenario.recreate()
    //...
```

I would suggest having some interface / abstract handler that you can unit test outside of Android context.